# Getting the occurrence of values using JpaRepository Queries

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a class named Submission and another SubmissionDAO for the repository. The submission class has a number of fields such as id, author, title,...

What I want to do is search through the database and get a list of (count, author) pairs for each author value in the database.

I made a query

```
@Query(value = "select author, count(*) from submissions GROUP BY author order by count(author) desc", nativeQuery = true)
List<Submission> findByAuthorOccurance();
```

Obviously, this doesn't work because it can't put the count value in the Submission object. 
My question is how would I go about getting this pair of values back to my controller?

I've tried searching but nothing comes up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone comes here in the future for whatever reason, I figured my problem out.

When you specify a range of data points to get from the query (ie author and count), it groups the values into object arrays (Object[]) and puts those in a normal List.

So my code ended up being like this:

```
@Query(value = "select author, count(*) from submissions GROUP BY author order by count(author) desc", nativeQuery = true)
List<Object[]> findByAuthorOccurance();
```

For the query and

```
   List<Object[]> map =submissionRepository.findByAuthorOccurance();
    for(Object[] objs : map){
        System.out.println((String)objs[0]+" : "+(BigInteger)objs[1]);
    }
```

To get the data.